# Rate of convergence

Tags: numerical-methods

Suppose that $p_{1},p_{2}>0$ and that $F_{i}(h)=L_{i}+O(h^{p_{i}})$ as $h \to {0^ + }$ for $i=1,2$. What are the rates of convergence of $F_{1}(h)F_{2}(h)$ for various values of $L_{1},L_{2}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just plugging in blindly,
if $p = \min(p_1, p_2)$,

$\begin{align}
F_1(h) F_2(h)
&= (L_1 + O(h^{p_1})(L_2 + O(h^{p_2})) \\
&= L_1 L_2 + L_1 O(h^{p_2}) + L_2 O(h^{p_1}) +  O(h^{p_1+p_2}) \\
&= L_1 L_2 + O(h^{p_2}) + O(h^{p_1}) +  O(h^{p_1+p_2}) \\
&= L_1 L_2 + O(h^{p}) \\
\end{align}
$

This depends on knowing that
$O(h^a) + O(h^b) = O(h^a)$
as $h \to 0$
if $0 < a < b$.
For example, $O(h)+O(h^2) = O(h)$
since $h^2$ is smaller than $h$ as $h \to 0$.

This, of course, could be considered somewhat abusive,
but I enjoy it.

Comment: Ah, thanks loads for that!